# Getting current line from another managed thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm using this code to give a time limit for another thread and interrupt it after certain time:

```
    void RunWithTimeout(Action action, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        AutoResetEvent signal = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        Thread workerThread = null;
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
        {
            workerThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
            action();
            signal.Set();
        });

        using (new Timer((o) => { signal.Set(); }, null, (int)timeout.TotalMilliseconds, Timeout.Infinite))
        {
            signal.WaitOne();
        }

        if (workerThread != null && workerThread.IsAlive)
        {
            try
            {
                workerThread.Abort();
            }
            catch { }
            throw new System.TimeoutException();
        }
    }
```

I'm using .NET 3.5 so I can't use Tasks
I'm throwing TimeoutException now but I would like to know the line that was being executed while calling `Abort`.

Is there a way to get call stack of another thread and pass it to the exception's `StackTrace` property?

Comment: Hmm, pretty unhealthy to assume there actually *is* a "current line" when code needs to be aborted.  It is almost certainly buried in an internal CLR or operating system function.  The kind that's required to make threads hang and not get their job done in time.  Aborting threads is hazardous, there's a million warnings out on the interwebs about it.

Comment: Aborting threads is so fraught with error that you shouldn't do it except in dire circumstances. If you have control of the code, you should write the thread to support some means of cooperative cancellation. In .NET 4.0, you could use `CancellationToken`. In earlier versions, use a `WaitHandle`. See my blog post, [Polling for cancellation](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/05/07/polling-for-cancellation/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't require a `Timer` to wait for the other thread, you can use the `WaitOne` overload that accepts a timeout in milliseconds.

To capture the stack trace on the worker thread, you can pass the `ThreadAbortException` to the main thread through a closure variable:

```
private static void RunWithTimeout(Action action, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    Thread worker = null;
    var signal = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    ThreadAbortException abortException = null;
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
    {
        worker = Thread.CurrentThread;
        try
        {
            action();
            signal.Set();
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException ex)
        {
            //thread is being aborted, pass the exception back to the main thread
            abortException = ex;
        }
    });

    if (!signal.WaitOne(timeout))
    {
        worker.Abort();
        //abortException is now filled from the worker thread, the stack trace for the 
        //worker thread is now inside the InnerException of the ThreadAbortException
        throw new TimeoutException("Operation timed out", abortException);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, `WaitOne` rather than a timer. By the way, there is a [WaitOne overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190477(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes a `TimeSpan`. So you can write `WaitOne(timeout)`, rather than converting to milliseconds first.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with catching `ThreadAbortException` as demonstrated below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var thread = new Thread(Work);
        thread.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        thread.Abort();
    }

    static void Work()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                // do work here
            }
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            // TODO: pass ex.StackTrace to main thread
        }
    }
}
```

The stack trace will include the name of the method in which the thread was when it was aborted. The `ThreadAbortException` will be rethrown automatically, so the thread is still aborted.